# When did The Talmud first become available to the readers as a written document?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, amoroim

What was the probable earliest time, when some Jewish readers could get a hold of a document that contains any material that belong to the material that is found in Talmud Sanhedrin?

What was the probable earliest time, when some Jewish readers could get a hold of a book that is called Talmud, even though it was still lacking a few passages that been added by those who edited it later?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a matter of intense debate with many book-length treatments.

Comment: Any material includes mishna, beraisa, and gemara, which makes a difference of centuries.